# I have great doubts solve this exercise by integral by parts $\int_{0}^1 \int_0^1 x\cdot e^{xy}\, dy\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have great doubts solve this exercise by integral by parts

$\int_{0}^1 \int_0^1 x\cdot e^{xy}\, dy\, dx$

Comment: This is an iterated integral. You don't need to integrate by parts if you integrate this as written. However, if you exchange the order before integrating, then integration by parts can help solve the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x e^{xy}\, dy \, dx$$

We anti-differentiate $x e^{xy}$, noting that $x$ is just a constant since we are doing this with respect to $y$.

$$\int_0^1 \left| e^{xy} \right|_{y=0}^1 \, dx$$

$$\int_0^1 (e^x - 1) \, dx$$

This is just one variable, so we should be in more familiar territory. We anti-differentiate with respect to $x$ and evaluate the result

$$\left|e^x - x\right|_{x=0}^1 = e-2$$

Answer (score 1):

let $S$ be the square $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$ and set $P(x,y)=e^{xy}$. then by Green's theorem:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 xe^{xy}dx dy =\int_S\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dx dy = -\int_{\partial S} Pdx \\
= -\int_0^1 dx - \int_1^0 e^x dx \\
= e-2
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** The integrand is positive. You may just write
$$
\int_{0}^1  e^{xy}\, dy=\frac{e^x-1}x
$$ then multiply by $x$ and integrate from $x=0^+$ to $1$.